# A Field has characteristic 0 if and only if it contains Q

Tags: field-theory, positive-characteristic

```
          I would like some help in proving the following statement:
```

**A field $K$ has characteristic 0 if and only if $\mathbb{Q}$ is a subfield of $K$.**

So, the way I have approached this is by first assuming that $K$ has characteristic 0 and then we know that there is an embedding of $\mathbb{Z}$ into K and since $n.1$ is in K, then, their inverses will also be in $K$ and hence the subfield that we get is the one generated by ${1}$ and this is the **prime subfield** of K and this is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$. So $K$ contains $\mathbb{Q}$. But I am not sure how to progress the other way.

(If you feel that the reasoning I have used above is wrong/can be improved, I would be extremely happy for it to be corrected.)

Comment: How to show that the prime subfield is isomorphic to Q ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your proof is fine. Actually, you have done the hard direction the other direction is easier ! Suppose that $\mathbb{Q}$ is a subfield of $K$. Then if we had an equation of the form
$$
1 + 1 + \ldots + 1  = 0
$$
in $K$, we would also have it in $\mathbb{Q}$ (because the $1$ is the same whether we view it in $K$ or in the subfield $\mathbb{Q}$). But we have no such equation in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Ahh! Yes that is definitely easier than the other direction. Thank You very much.  With regards to the first direction, technically speaking, the field of characterisitic 0 doesn't necessarily contain $\mathbb{Q}$ does it? It rather contains a field which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @user1314 Yes, I agree. However, you could say that it contains a field which is "naturally" isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$, which is stronger. The point is that there is one and only one copy of $\mathbb{Q}$ in that field (embedded as a subfield). (Compare this to the case of a vector space, say. If I give you a 4-dimensional real vector space, there's lots and lots of 2-dimensional real vector spaces inside of it, and no way to say any copy is "better" than the others, at least not without picking a basis. So it would be a more dangerous abuse of language to say $V$ contains $\mathbb{R}^2$.)